# How to sign all the msi file which are under folder?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, code-signing

I am using signtool to sign my msi.

How to recursively search all the msi in a folder and subfolder then sign them all?

Comment: What signtool? Is it command line capable?

Comment: Yes. It is an exe which can be executed from commandline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The previous 2 answers show a PowerShell solution.
You can accomplish this easily enough from a CMD.EXE Command Prompt as well.

```
for /r "yourRootFolder" %F in (*.msi) do signtool sign /a "%F"
```

Obviously you need to modify your signtool options to suit your needs. The important bit is %F will iteretively hold the name of each .MSI file.

If you want to run the command from within a batch file, then the % must be doubled, so %F becomes %%F in both places.

Comment: After needing to sign more than 10 files, you should make a variable for the paths and sign after you have all the files string.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example using a code signing certificate (I have only one certificate in $cert):

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert: -CodeSigningCert -Recurse
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MsiFolder -Filter *.msi -Recurse | Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know what command line parameters you need for the MSI signing tool are you can get all MSIs under a given folder like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -path C:\MsiFolder -Include *.msi | ForEach-Object {
    $msiPath = $_.FullName
    $output = & the_msi_sign_tool.exe -msifile $msiPath -parameterB -parameterC 2>&1
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        Write-Error $output
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Only one password prompt!**

```
$signExe = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe'
$files = gci 'C:\Temp\*' -Include *.msi | %{('"{0}"' -f $_.FullName)}
$fingerprint = '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
$timestampUrl = 'http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced'

$filesInputArg = $files -join " "
.$signExe sign /tr $timestampUrl /td SHA256 /sha1 $fingerprint $filesInputArg
```